# Grails static mapping for String[]

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am trying to store a string[] in a database with grails but tinyblob isn't large enough.  I've tried changing the mapping to blob and longblob but when I do this I get an error:

```
[Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.sql.Blob
```

Next I tried changing the maxSize within the domain constraints but I get the error

```
No such property: maxSize for class:
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: Are you using `type` or `sqlType` for the mapping? Also, wether you can store String[] as a blob (and be able to use it) depends on your DBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm curious about your reasoning for doing this.  If you are just trying to have many string associated to a domain class you can do that directly like this:

```
    static hasMany = [whatevers: String]
```

Answer (score 0):

A blob is not a string array, it is a byte array, byte[]. Try changing the string to a byte array and persist it in that form.